# What is the right way to setup a database for web applications with big grow potential?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im a software engineer (finished my software engineer study a couple of months ago) and for my work i develop a large scalable web application. Another firm does the programming work and makes the database behind it. We defined the data and the relations between them but didn't give a hard database structure they should use.

Now the first (internal) things are visable. I looked in the database structure behind ans saw (in my opinion) something weirds.

For users they created a table users which contains stuff like id, email and password. Near this they created an user_meta table which contains an id, key and value.

When i have a user with:

- userid
- email
- password
- name
- lastname
- address
- phone

the id, email and password is stored in the user table. For the other information are rows created in the user_meta table. This means in this case there are 4 rows created for 1 user (in our case are this more than 20 rows for each user) This structure is user for every object what should be saved in the database.

I learned to create a table which contains all the data which is necessary for the user. So in my logic it should be one table with 7 fields. Because i have not much experience in practice (since i ready with my bachelor of sience software engineer for a few months ago) i'm a bit confused about the structure which is used by the IT Firm.

---

Extra information:

- Our software is build on the Laravel framework (on my advice)
- Our software uses MySQL database

---

Questions:

- Is this a normal way to create database for large systems or something like that, because i never see this in my study or other projects in my live.
- Is this best or bad practice?
- In my opinion this is bad for performance. Especially when the user count grows, is this true? or can this be done to get the performance high (because not a whole record needs to be selected ?(in our case we expect AT LEAST 100.000 users at the end of 2017 which wil grow faster and faster when our project passes. there is a material chance that we grow far above 1.000.000 users in a few years)
- I think the reason why they do it like this is that the "objects" can be changed very easy but in my opinion is it always possible to add fields to an table and you should NEVER delete fields (also not when it is possible by the structure of the database), is my opinion in this right?

sorry when the questions are "noob questions" but for me this is the first big project in my live so i miss some experience but try to manage the project professionally. We will discuss this Wednesday in an meeting. On this way i want to prepare my self a bit in this theme.

Comment: I personally don't like relational tables which act like key-value stores, which is what's going on here with the `user-meta` table. However, it's useful in the cases where there's a lot of fields associated to a user which may be null-able.

Comment: The performance parts depends on how many searches are going to be included in specific timeframe. so if you only retrieve these records and you have indexed the entity ids it will probably be fine.

Comment: Sounds interesting, so when i search for all all values of user 3 i don't need to loop trough all records of user 1 and 2 only i loop to the first item of user 1, first item of user 2 and then i find my records ? do i understand this right with "indexing" ? In my logic you need to loop over 2x 4 records so 8 instead of 2?